# Export 2007 list and import to 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, 2007

I have a giant list in a sharepoint 2007 site. I want to move it over to my 2013 site I'm creating. I've been exporting to excel then using the import excel app. However, the list has pdf attachments for some of the rows. Everything is importing just fine besides the attachments. They aren't even there. Is there a way around this? Possibly Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the easiest way I think would be to manually bring over the attachments, it may be possible to capture all the attachments using SharePoint Designer 2007, then importing them using SharePoint Designer 2013.

Comment: There's got to be a way. Can you copy the attachment row in data sheet view then add it to the data sheet view of 2013 or something?

Comment: by row I mean column

Comment: The Row is specific to textual data, not attachments. All the attachment field is essentially is a link to the attachment file that is stored inside the attachment folder of the list. Copying a row of data would be exactly like copying a row in excel, the attachment is not embedded in this case. Another way of doing this would really be to upgrade the sharepoint content database to 2010, then to 2013, then exporting the list and importing it to the 2013 destination site.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys! I'm looking in to these things.